# Image handling error. Unsupported output format (image/png)

Tags: mapserver

getting this weird error saying that image/png is not supported.

```
[Sun Jul 23 22:58:24 2017].672000 msFreeMap(): freeing map at 00000000007DA390.
[Sun Jul 23 22:59:00 2017].99000 msWMSLoadGetMapParams(): Image handling error. Unsupported output format (image/png).
[Sun Jul 23 22:59:00 2017].247000 msFreeMap(): freeing map at 00000000007D9D30.
```

below I attach the mapfile:

```
MAP
  CONFIG "PROJ_LIB" "H:\\mapserverlib\\bin\\proj\\SHARE"
  CONFIG "MS_ERRORFILE" "H:\\mapfiles\\log.txt"
  DEBUG 5
  EXTENT 1433525.798872 -4480198.522214 6502586.830347 4615124.978985
  FONTSET "C:\\temp\\font.list"
  IMAGECOLOR 255 170 204
  IMAGETYPE "png"
  NAME "MapName0"
  RESOLUTION 90
  SIZE -1 -1
  STATUS ON
  UNITS METERS

  OUTPUTFORMAT
    NAME "png"
    MIMETYPE "image/png"
    DRIVER "AGG/PNG"
    EXTENSION "png"
    IMAGEMODE RGBA
    TRANSPARENT TRUE
    FORMATOPTION "GAMMA=0.75"
  END # OUTPUTFORMAT

  OUTPUTFORMAT
    NAME "png8"
    MIMETYPE "image/png; mode=8bit"
    DRIVER "AGG/PNG8"
    EXTENSION "png"
    IMAGEMODE RGBA
    TRANSPARENT TRUE
    FORMATOPTION "QUANTIZE_FORCE=on"
    FORMATOPTION "QUANTIZE_COLORS=256"
    FORMATOPTION "GAMMA=0.75"
  END # OUTPUTFORMAT

  OUTPUTFORMAT
    NAME "jpeg"
    MIMETYPE "image/jpeg"
    DRIVER "AGG/JPEG"
    EXTENSION "jpg"
    IMAGEMODE RGB
    TRANSPARENT FALSE
  END # OUTPUTFORMAT

  PROJECTION
    "init=epsg:2964"
  END # PROJECTION
  LEGEND
    KEYSIZE 20 10
    KEYSPACING 5 5
    LABEL
      SIZE 10
      OFFSET 0 0
      SHADOWSIZE 1 1
    END # LABEL
    STATUS OFF
  END # LEGEND

  QUERYMAP
    SIZE -1 -1
    STATUS OFF
    STYLE HILITE
  END # QUERYMAP

  SCALEBAR
    INTERVALS 4
    LABEL
      SIZE 10
      OFFSET 0 0
      SHADOWSIZE 1 1
    END # LABEL
    SIZE 200 3
    STATUS OFF
    UNITS MILES
  END # SCALEBAR

  WEB
    METADATA
      "wms_srs" "EPSG:2964"
      "wms_onlineresource"  "http://127.0.0.1:8000/map"
      "wms_getcapabilities_version" "1.3"
      "wms_getmap_formatlist"   ""
      "wms_service_onlineresource"  "http://127.0.0.1:8000/map"
      "wms_getlegendgraphic_formatlist" ""
      "ows_enable_request"  "*"
      "wms_feature_info_mime_type"  "text/html"
      "ows_schemas_location"    "http://schemas.opengis.net"
      "wms_timeformat"  "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
      "wms_encoding"    "ISO-8859-1"
      "wms_title"   "Mapserver metadata"
    END # METADATA
  END # WEB

  LAYER
    DATA "H:\\gisdata\\airports.shp"
    DEBUG 5
    EXTENT 1433525.798872 -4480198.522214 6502586.830347 4615124.978985
    METADATA
      "wms_title"   "ShapeFile"
    END # METADATA
    NAME "ShapeFile"
    STATUS ON
    TILEITEM "location"
    TYPE POINT
    UNITS METERS
    CLASS
    # Start of the first Style
    STYLE
      # Symbol to be used (reference)
      SYMBOL "square"
      # Size of the symbol in pixels
      SIZE 16
      # Colour (RGB) - red
      COLOR 255 0 0
      # Outline colour (RGB) - black
      OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
    END # end of STYLE
    # Start of the second Style
    STYLE
      # Symbol to be used (reference)
      SYMBOL "circle"
      # Size of the symbol in pixels
      SIZE 10
      # Colour (RGB) - blue
      COLOR 0 0 255
    END # end of STYLE
  END # end of CLASS
  END # LAYER

END # MAP
```

Anything unusual? Any idea of what might be going on?

Request sample:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/map?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&width=500&height=300&styles=&layers=ShapeFile&format=image/png&crs=&bbox=-4480198.522214,1433525.798872,4615124.978985,6502586.830347
```

MapServer info

```
    <!--
     MapServer version 7.0.4 OUTPUT=PNG OUTPUT=JPEG OUTPUT=KML 
SUPPORTS=PROJ SUPPORTS=AGG SUPPORTS=FREETYPE SUPPORTS=CAIRO 
SUPPORTS=SVG_SYMBOLS SUPPORTS=SVGCAIRO SUPPORTS=ICONV 
SUPPORTS=FRIBIDI SUPPORTS=WMS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WMS_CLIENT 
SUPPORTS=WFS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WFS_CLIENT SUPPORTS=WCS_SERVER 
SUPPORTS=SOS_SERVER SUPPORTS=FASTCGI SUPPORTS=THREADS 
SUPPORTS=GEOS INPUT=JPEG INPUT=POSTGIS INPUT=OGR INPUT=GDAL 
INPUT=SHAPEFILE 
    -->
```

Comment: Could not reproduce your bug. What is your mapserver request?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/map?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&width=500&height=300&styles=&layers=ShapeFile&format=image/png&crs=&bbox=-4480198.522214,1433525.798872,4615124.978985,6502586.830347

Comment: Did you specify the Output formats correctly ? http://mapserver.org/mapfile/outputformat.html

Comment: I also note that you state layer units as METERS but [EPSG:2964](http://epsg.io/2964) has `US survey foot` as its unit of measure.

Answer (score 1):

> Anything unusual? Any idea of what might be going on?

Based on your sample request:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/map?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&width=500&height=300&styles=&layers=ShapeFile&format=image/png&crs=&bbox=-4480198.522214,1433525.798872,4615124.978985,6502586.830347`

One thing that might be going wrong is you do not specify the CRS (`crs=&`)  should be `crs=EPSG:2964&`

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with it. Won't it just take the layers default CRS when crs is not specified from the request?

Comment: @RoVo Might not be the cause, but when I try a GetMap request  without specifying the projection, the default projection is not picked up and instead I get error: `<ServiceException code="InvalidCRS">msWMSLoadGetMapParams(): WMS server error. Unsupported CRS namespace (only EPSG, AUTO2, CRS currently supported).</ServiceException>`